# Spiderweb chart with circular gridline interpolation: Label is seen very far away from Plotline

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have spiderweb chart with plotline at a specific value. Gridline interploation is used as circle. In this case, label provided is displayed very far away from plotline (top left corner of chart) by default.

how can i always display labels at center or at specific position of plotline circle, without manually calculating x and y points.

Refer example: http://jsfiddle.net/2862pqma/4/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'line'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Budget vs spending',
    x: -80
  },

  pane: {
    size: '80%'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support',
      'Information Technology', 'Administration'
    ],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0
  },

  yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'circle',
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0,
    plotLines: [{
      value: 35000,
      width: 2,
      dashStyle: "Solid",
      color: "red",
      label: {
        text: "Line Marker",
        style: {
          color: "red"
        }
      }
    }]
  },

  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
  },

  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 70,
    layout: 'vertical'
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Allocated Budget',
    data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
  }, ]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `x` and `y` parameters for positioning the label : [Link to documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines.label.x)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need to calculate label position in polar chart, although it is not hard. Use `Axis.toPixels` function to change axis values into pixels and use them as `x` and `y` positions of label. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.toPixels
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines.label.x
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotLines.label.y

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/z7ya2r9y/